# No result returned when calling async local request in a Unit Test

Tags: c#

Can you see anything obvious I'm missing? I'm trying to create a unit test that calls a local web api but I'm not getting what is expected.

Article resource I'm using is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client).

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestAutocomplete()
{

    string resource = "api/products?parm=test";

    Task<Class1> product = GetProductAsync(resource);
}
async Task<Class1> GetProductAsync(string path)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    // Update port # in the following line.
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:22292/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
    Class1 product = null;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Class1>();
    }
    return product;
}
```

...

```
public class Class1
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string street_line { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

**Update:**
After changing:

```
Task<Class1> product = GetProductAsync(resource);
```

to

```
Class1 product = GetProductAsync(resource).Result;
```

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'AddressValidationAPI.Tests.Class1' because the type requires a JSON
>   object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix
>   this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."}

[image]

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What is unexpected? The code runs exactly as have. If you want to perform that Task without making the method async, then use `.Result`

Comment: I’m expecting Class1 product to be populated but instead it’s the image that shows above. No address information returns.

Comment: because you are returning a Task. It's not a product. You need to execute that task. Either switch the method to async and use await, or use `GetProductAsync(resource).Result`

Comment: @LukeVo, I tried .Result and getting error...see OP towards bottom.

Comment: Please show the result of the request as the raw JSON. You'll likely find it starts with `[`, which can only be deserialized as a collection (as the error message says). So do `ReadAsync<List<Class1>>()`.

Comment: That worked! However, I copied this directly from the MSDN article and it wasn't a List<Product> for the ReadAsync, Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments under the OP. Here's the final unit test. Thanks everyone.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestAutocomplete()
{
    string resource = "api/addresses";
    List<AutocompleteSuggestions> suggests = GetAutocompleteSuggestions(resource).Result;
    Assert.AreEqual(1, suggests.Count);
}
async Task<List<AutocompleteSuggestions>> GetAutocompleteSuggestions(string path)
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:22292/");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(path);
        List<AutocompleteSuggestions> suggests = null;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            suggests = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<AutocompleteSuggestions>>();
        }
        return suggests;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `Task<Class1> GetProductAsync` does not return `Class1` (note that you should name it properly), but a `Task<Class1>`, and you do not have any code to execute it to get the result.

You have to execute it, either by the recommended proper way:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestAutocomplete()
{
    string resource = "api/addresses";
    List<AutocompleteSuggestions> suggests = await GetAutocompleteSuggestions(resource);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, suggests.Count);
}
```

Another small note, it's also recommended to rename `GetAutocompleteSuggestions` into `GetAutocompleteSuggestionsAsync` so you know you should await it.

If you absolutely cannot switch it to async method (for example, in Main method - which recently supported too, or when your Test framework does not support it), use:

```
List<AutocompleteSuggestions> suggests = GetAutocompleteSuggestions(resource).Result;
```

Further reference: [Asynchronous programming with async and await (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

The latter error is simply a mis-structure in your JSON/model class. You just have to check and reconcile between the two.